# jQuery Thickbox with .ASHX image handler - shows garbage

Tags: asp.net, jquery, thickbox

I am using an .ASHX handler to return images from my ASP.NET app.  When I use the browser to hit the URL directly (example):

```
  http://localhost/myapp/GetImage.ashx?key=12
```

it works fine... image shows up on the page.  but when I use that same link as a target in Thickbox... I get this:

[alt text http://franceschina.net/temp/thickbox.png](http://franceschina.net/temp/thickbox.png)

the distilled version of ASHX the code:

```
   byte[] img = (byte[])pp.PRODUCT_PHOTO1.ToArray();
   context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
   context.Response.OutputStream.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
```

any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can do this sort of thing locally. Is it throwing up any errors in the error console? Have you tried it on a webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/140371:

In the Thickbox module, the main *.js file, thickbox.js does not account for image urls created in drupal, e.g. via /image/view/2321/preview instead of /image.jpg (or *gif or *png). If thickbox.js does not see the file name itself (gif, jpg, png, jpeg) in the link anchor tag (the [a href ...] tag), it will treat the image like another mime type that is not an image. This causes Thickbox to spit out God-awful garbage on top of your page instead of a cool shadowbox (lightbox) effect.

Looks like the same issue you're having.

Comment: wow... good job... this was right on. I modified those two lines in thickbox to add ".ashx" extension, and it works! since this is the REAL answer to the question, I will accept it...  but I'm not actually going to implement this solution (I'm going to stick with the iFrame) because I don't want to deal with a custom thickbox script

Answer (score 0):

well I ended up using the iframe option of ThickBox to load my image with another page.  I don't love this solution (it requires a separate page and extra code to determine the optimal height/width of the iFrame)... but it works and I don't have any more time to mess with it